# Google Cloud Platform App Deployment Resulted in 502 Server Error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

After making sure that my RESTful API works fine locally, I followed the instructions in the following guide to deploy it:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

... and I believe I did it right. I got the following screen after
gcloud app deploy
finished running.

[image: App Deployment Result - Logs from the Command Line]

Sadly, https://_project-id.appspot.com (or gcloud app browse on the command line) keeps leading to a 502 Server Error:

Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

(and yes, I tried again multiple times)

========================================================
Edit:
When I checked the Deployment Manager, it says:
You don't have any deployments yet.

## What would be the problem here?

app.yaml

```
# Copyright 2015-2016, Google, Inc.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
# [START runtime]
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
# [END runtime]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "plusfriend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Jjalkey Kakao Plus Friend/YellowID RESTful API",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "*",
    "express": "4.14.1",
    "mongoose": "4.8.1",
    "gcloud": "^0.37.0"
  },
  "author": "Edward Joon-Hyuk Chang",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Last part of server.js

```
// Listen
app.listen(80);
```

Any ideas what I should do?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What do your logs say? (`gcloud app logs read`)

Comment: @Zachary It just repeats: plusfriend@1.0.0 start /app node server.js (like in the picture above)

Comment: Any chance that the app is not actually listening, or has died?

Comment: @jarmod It was listening fine locally.. This is my first time trying to deploy something and I have no idea what the problem is

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If so please share~!

Comment: @EdwardJoon-HyukChang: please don't add text/logs as images, instead copy-paste the text (and format it accordingly) inside your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for this problem, I just restructured everything. You can see the files here: https://github.com/edwardjhchang/Jjalkey-Kakao-Talk-Plus-Friend-Auto-Reply-API

Most of all, you must create `var http = require('http');`
(which I did not realize initially). Check my repository for more details :D